# Android if my launcher has not started and pressing home button

Tags: android, startup, launcher

I've developed a launcher. In my device, there are 3 launcher with my application and the default launcher of Android. If I have not launched my application before, when I press home, my application appears on the launcher list. So, when I touch my launcher, it occurs error because of I didn't start it before. What can I do to solve this problem?


My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.comeks.deneme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.comeks.deneme.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".main.java"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why did you feel the need to have three launchers with your application?

Comment: I'm sorry for I was not clear. I just gave example. I have more than 1 launcher in my device. My own launcher has not started before. But when I press home button, my own launcher comes to the launcher list. When I choose my launcher, it occurs this error: "Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped". But after I launch my application, no problem...

Comment: Ah ok. Can you post your manifest. I think that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the name of the file of your second activity?
main.java.java?

Do you even have two different activities?

Comment: Actually, I don't. I've watch this video and wrote this code: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn0UoFcv79c

Comment: You're right! I removed the repeated activity. Then I added the extra 2 lines to the first activity, it's OK now!